How do I access passkeys seamlessly in an iMessage app?
Does anyone know how to access passkeys from an iMessage app? I'd like to do it seamlessly without having to re-route users through Safari.
I've looked through Apple developer docs and forums. Unfortunately no mention of anything like this.
